# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am getting the following error in a Spring-MVC app using hibernate:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>minimal.example</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringSecurityLoginDatabase</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringSecurityLoginDatabase</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring --><!-- 3.2.5.RELEASE worked -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>


    <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
    <jaxb-impl.version>2.2.7</jaxb-impl.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Bean validation -->
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

    <!-- Database access -->
    <tomcat-jdbc.version>8.0.23</tomcat-jdbc.version>
    <ehcache.version>2.6.6</ehcache.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.1</hsqldb.version>

    <!-- AOP -->
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- RSS -->
    <rome.version>1.0</rome.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>

    <!-- Dates -->
    <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.1.0.CR8</jadira-usertype-core.version>


    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>2.3.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.10.3</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.0.3-1</webjars-jquery.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.27</mysql.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>${jadira-usertype-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING, SPRING, SPRINGITY SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- used for EhCcheCcheManager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-jdbc.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For MySql only -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>${mysql.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Webjars (static dependencies distributed as JAR files) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- used by Spring MVC Test framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- commons lang dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>           
    </dependency>                        

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--
            Force the version of all the spring jars (core, beans, context, ...) 
            pulled by spring-data-jpa:1.3.4.RELEASE to 3.2.x when spring-data pulls 
            the 3.1.x versions to prevent some misbehaviors of maven which sometimes 
            pulls both 3.2.x and 3.1.x versions of spring-core, spring-beans and spring-context
        -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Maven plugin versions are mentioned in order to guarantee the build reproducibility in the long term -->
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <!-- declared explicitly so Spring config files can be placed next to their corresponding JUnit test class 
            (see example with ValidatorTests) -->
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
      </testResource>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Xlint />
                </compilerArguments>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>n_factor_auth</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                <port>9966</port>
                <path>/n_factor_auth</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My `sdnext-servlet.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava.security" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

The complete stack trace when tomcat tries to launch the app from within eclipse is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have been reading other postings about this error. including [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447189/cannot-find-class-org-springframework-orm-hibernate3-annotation-annotationsessi), but the other answers have not worked in this situation, so I am posting a new question to identify other possible causes.  **How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: Where did you find `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`? See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got it from another SO post, as a recommended fix for the hibernate3 version of the same, which was causing an error in a project that I recently imported.  ....  Hey, thank you very much for getting back to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Change your AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Ref: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8096